Chromatic number of simple graphs
It's known that the standard graph with vertices $\mathbb{Z}^d$ and nearest neighbor edges is bipartite and can be partitioned into even/odd subsets.
What about the graph $\mathbb{Z}^d$ with nearest and next-nearest neighbor edges? Do we know that the minimal $k$ such that it is $k$-partite?
Can we be more general and consider a graph on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ with edges $xy$ where $|x-y| \le r$ for some fixed $r$?
For general graphs, I think this corresponds to the chromatic number, but are the values known for the specific examples above.

I give an answer to the first question, i. e., for the case $r = 2$, and I suppose Manhattan metrics (aka taxicab geometry), i. e., next-nearest neighbor is a nearest neighbor of the nearest neighbor.
I state that $\chi(G_{d, 2}) = 2d + 1$, where $G_{d, r}$ is an infinite graph with vertices in point of $\mathbb Z^d$ and edges between points on Manhattan distance at most $r$. Firstly note that there is a clique on $2d + 1$ vertices in $G_{d, 2}$. Pick any vertex and both its nearest neighbors for every dimension. Every pair of these $2d + 1$ vertices are adjacent. That's why $\chi(G_{d, 2}) \ge 2d + 1$.
One the other hand let's make the following vertex coloring. Let's number dimensions from $1$ to $d$. Along $i$-th dimension nearest neighbors of vertex with color $c$ have colors $c + i$ and $c - i$ modulo $2d + 1$. Now note that $c \pm i \pm j = c$ modulo $2d + 1$ only if $i = j$ and signs are different. But this is a way to get back to the same vertex. That's why any pair of adjacent vertices have different colors.
Upd. I. e., the vertex corresponding to the point $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_d)$ gets color $(x_1 + 2x_2 + \cdots + dx_d) \bmod (2d + 1)$. So $\chi(G_{d, 2}) \le 2d + 1$ and therefore $\chi(G_{d, 2}) = 2d + 1$.
Let's consider other values of $r$.
It is easy to see that $G_{0, r}$ is infinite empty graph, so $\chi(G_{0, r}) = 1$.
For $d = 1$ a vertex and its $r$ closest neigbors to the right form a clique of cardinality $r + 1$ in $G_{1, r}$, therefore $\chi(G_{1, r}) \ge r + 1$. At the same time giving to the vertex $i$ color $i \bmod (r + 1)$ we get a coloring of vertices of $G_{1, r}$ in $r + 1$ colors, because vertices $i$ and $i + r + 1$ are not adjacent for all $i \in \mathbb Z$. So $\chi(G_{1, r}) \le r + 1$ and therefore $\chi(G_{1, r}) = r + 1$.
Also for every even $r$ we can get a lower bound in the same way as for $r = 2$: consider a vertex and all its neigbors at distance at most $r/2$. These vertices form a clique. The number $f(d, r/2)$ of lattice points inside $d$-dimensional Manhattan sphere of radius $r/2$ is a lower bound for the chromatic number and we can use the following recurrent relation to count it:
$$\chi(G_{d, r}) \ge f(d, r/2) = \begin{cases}1, &\text{if } d = 0 \text{ or } r = 0,\\ f(d - 1, r/2) + f(d - 1, r/2 - 1) + f(d, r/2 - 1) & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
For odd $r$ this lower bound can be increased a bit, but not essentially. At the same time a simple upper bound is $(r + 1)^d$ which comes from coloring all points inside every hypercube with $r + 1$ integer points on each linear edge into different colors.
